# 4K with Intel UHD Graphics 620 and Thunderbolt 3 Docking station

Tags: windows-10, displayport, docking-station, 4k-resolution

I want 4k with 60Hz. I have a Lenovo laptop with

- Intel Core i7-8665U
- Intel UHD Graphics 620
- connected to a Thunderbolt 3 Dock gen 2 docking station.
- To that docking station I want to connect a 4k monitor to it (Samsung U32R594CWU) through a 4k- displayport 1.2 cable. The monitor is also set to use Displayport 1.2.

But I can't get it to work with 60Hz. Only with 30Hz. What am I doing wrong? I even installed the monitor driver into Windows 10.

On top of that I would also like to connect another older FullHD monitor to the docking station (DVI input over a HDMI cable with adapter) but that forces the 4k monitor to reduce the resolution to FullHD also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dock you mention is a [Lenovo Thunderbolt 3 Dock Gen 2](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd500265).  It's [user manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/options/thinkpad_thunderbolt3_ug_en_201812.pdf) has this section:

[image: Resolutions]

If it is running at 30Hz, then you must not be using a USB-C Connector that is Thunderbolt 3 compatible, and this appears to be true, since you said you are using Display Port to connect to the monitor.  In order to get the monitor to run at 60Hz, you will need to use the USB-C Connector that is Thunderbolt 3 compatible on the front of the dock:

[image: Connector]

Comment: That is an interesting option I did not consider yet. I will try using that port and get me such a cable tomorrow. But currently I use one of the Displayport connectors on the back of that docking station to  connect to my monitor. It should work too, right?

Comment: @juergend have a look at the manual I've linked.  While DP 1.2 should be able to run a 4k screen at 60Hz, the [cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Cable_bandwidth_and_certifications) must be able to handle it.  Additionally, your graphics chip must be able to as well.  However, I think the dock has some sort of limitation in this case. These are the same docks at my company, and people with 4k screens were complaining about the same thing.  Also, look at page 8 of the manual.  It says you cannot mix the inputs (one monitor on DP, one on HDMI). Might explain your other issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the USB-C cable (I use a USB-C to Displayport cable). Connecting it to the port you refer at the docking station did not work actually. The monitor was not detected by windows. But I used the cable to connect it to the USB-C port at my laptop and it works now with 60Hz and I could even connect my old FullHD monitor to the docking station too and both monitors work together! Awesome!